# How do I delete the end-of-line to the right of my cursor?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Say I have the following text open in vi:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text [CURSOR]
of the  printing and ...
```

The cursor position is denoted by [CURSOR]

How can I delete the end-of-line that follows the cursor so that the next line wraps around?

Comment: `help J`, `help join`... im almost certain theres a dupe to be found somewhere.

Comment: Maybe not! Guess this will be my join dupe now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal mode, use the `J` command. From the Ex command line, prefer `join`.

There are also variants, such as `gJ`.

Comment: Ahhh thanks ... I've been looking for this for like 20 years :/